# Correct use of function pointers

Tags: c, function-pointers

The doubly-linked list upon which I have based a fair amount of code appears to have a bug in it related to the way that I go about deleting nodes from the list, but I am unable to spot it. Consider the following code:

```
typedef struct DL_LIST
{
    uint16 tag;
    struct DL_LIST *previous;
    struct DL_LIST *next;
    void *object;
    uint32 size;
} DL_LIST;
```

The function used to delete nodes is as follows:

```
void dl_delete(DL_LIST *node, void (*destructor)(void*))
{
    assert(destructor != NULL);

    if (node != NULL)
    {
        dl_extract(node);

        if (node->object != NULL)
        {
            destructor(node->object);
        }

        free(node);
    }
}
```

where:

```
DL_LIST *dl_extract(DL_LIST *node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        if (node->previous != NULL)
        {
            node->previous->next = node->next;
        }

        if (node->next != NULL)
        {
            node->next->previous = node->previous;
        }

        node->previous = NULL;
        node->next = NULL;
    }

    return node;
}
```

Is anyone able to spot the problem with the way I am deleting nodes? The reason I believe that there is a problem is that I have used `DL_LIST` as the basis for a queue structure, and the function used to delete items from the queue corrupts it, *except* when I comment out the call to `dl_delete`.

EDIT 1. As requested in the comments, the queue code follows:

```
typedef struct QU_LIST
{
    DL_LIST *list;
    uint32 count;
} QU_LIST;

uint8 qu_remove(QU_LIST *queue, void *object, void (*destructor)(void*))
{
    uint8 result = QU_SUCCESS;
    uint32 size;
    DL_LIST *first_node;
    DL_LIST *next_node;
    void *marker;

    assert(queue != NULL && destructor != NULL);

    if (queue->count > 0)
    {
        first_node = dl_get_first(queue->list);
        next_node = dl_get_next(first_node);

        marker = dl_get_object(first_node, NULL, &size);

        if (marker != NULL)
        {
            if (object != NULL)
            {
                memcpy(object, marker, size);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = QU_NO_MEMORY;
        }

        queue->list = next_node;

        dl_delete(first_node, destructor); // this is the problem

        --queue->count;
    }
    else
    {
        result = QU_EMPTY;
    }

    return result;
}
```

where:

```
DL_LIST *dl_get_first(DL_LIST *list)
{
    if (list != NULL)
    {
        while (list->previous != NULL)
        {
            list = list->previous;
        }
    }

    return list;
}

DL_LIST *dl_get_next(DL_LIST *node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        node = node->next;
    }

    return node;
}

void *dl_get_object(DL_LIST *node, uint16 *tag, uint32 *size)
{
    void *marker = NULL;

    if (node != NULL)
    {
        if (tag != NULL)
        {
            *tag = node->tag;
        }

        if (size != NULL)
        {
            *size = node->size;
        }

        marker = node->object;
    }

    return marker;
}
```

EDIT 2. Thanks to a sterling answer on the part of Wumpus Q. Wumbley, the source of the problem has been narrowed down to the following code, which is part of a navigation button library for an embedded system.

```
void bu_test(void)
{
    QU_LIST button_list = {0};
    BU_OBJECT *object = NULL;

    object = bu_create("O");
    // object->identifier is "O" at this point.

    bu_add(&button_list, "N");
    bu_add(&button_list, "S");
    bu_add(&button_list, "E");
    bu_add(&button_list, "W");

    qu_remove(&button_list, object, (void(*)(void*)) &_destructor);
    // object->identifier should be "N" at this point, but is not.
}
```

where:

```
typedef struct BU_OBJECT
{
    char *identifier;
} BU_OBJECT;

uint8 bu_add(QU_LIST *queue, char *identifier)
{
    uint8 result = BU_SUCCESS;
    BU_OBJECT* object;

    assert(queue != NULL && identifier != NULL);

    object = bu_create(identifier);

    if (object != NULL)
    {
        result = qu_add(queue, _TAG, object, sizeof(*object));

        if (result == QU_NO_MEMORY)
        {
            _destructor(object);

            result = BU_NO_MEMORY;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = BU_NO_MEMORY;
    }

    return result;
}
```

and:

```
BU_OBJECT *bu_create(char *identifier)
{
    BU_OBJECT *object = NULL;
    char *p;

    assert(identifier != NULL);

    object = malloc(sizeof(*object));

    if (object != NULL)
    {
        p = malloc(sizeof(*identifier));

        if (p != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(p, identifier);
            object->identifier = p;
        }
        else
        {
            free(object);
            object = NULL;
        }
    }

    return object;
}
```

and finally:

```
void _destructor(BU_OBJECT *object)
{  
    free(object->identifier);
    free(object);
}
```

Objects are added to the `button_list` without error, but it appears that `_destructor` is destroying the object parameter that is passed to the function `qu_remove`, which seems extremely strange to me, as it should be the object of the `first_node` that is destroyed, not that of the parameter.

Comment: I read it didn't spot any bugs. Post some more

Comment: Code looks fine to me too. Assuming all the pointers (next, previous, and object) are either valid or NULL, should be fine.

Comment: The most delicate part seems to be the memcpy. Are you sure the second argument to `qu_remove` is pointing to a big enough memory area?

Comment: @Wumpus Fairly sure. The `qu_remove` function is called from yet another function that creates a local object, and then passes a pointer to that object to `qu_remove`.

Comment: If there is a memory corruption issue, you might want to use `valgrind` or some other memory debugging tool to help you isolate it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. It lies not with the code, but with my *understanding* of it. To illustrate, consider the following line from the function `qu_remove`:

```
memcpy(object, marker, &size);
```

Prior to the call to `memcpy`, the content of `object` and `marker` in `qu_remove` are as follows:

```
Location      Content       Location Description
--------      -------       --------------------
0x1FFF8658    0x1FFF8668    Pointer to object (object)
0x1FFF8668    "O"           Pointer to identifier

0x1FFF86B0    0x1FFF8688    Pointer to object (marker)
0x1FFF8688    "N"           Pointer to identifier
```

After the call to `memcpy`, the content of `object` is as follows:

```
Location      Content       Location Description
--------      -------       --------------------
0x1FFF8658    0x1FFF8688    Pointer to object (marker)
0x1FFF8688    "N"           Pointer to identifier
```

For some reason I thought that `memcpy` would of copied the character "N" from location 0x1FFF8688 (the location of the identifier in `marker`) to 0x1FFF8668 (the location of the identifier in `object`). I now see that this is nonsense. The character "N" is not part of `marker`, and is therefore not copied - only the pointer to "N" is copied.

Knowing this explains the failure of the `bu_test` function. The tricky bit will be figuring out a way to solve the problem. What I will need is to write a replacement for `memcpy` that follows any pointer chains right down to the object that is being pointed-to, and copies that as well.

Comment: +1 for posting a detailed explanation of the problem for others. Don't be a denvercoder! :p

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete program which uses your functions (all that you posted so far) exactly as they are. It works. The bug is in the part you aren't showing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef uint8_t uint8;
typedef uint16_t uint16;
typedef uint32_t uint32;
enum { QU_SUCCESS, QU_NO_MEMORY, QU_EMPTY };

typedef struct DL_LIST
{
    uint16 tag;
    struct DL_LIST *previous;
    struct DL_LIST *next;
    void *object;
    uint32 size;
} DL_LIST;

DL_LIST *dl_extract(DL_LIST *node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        if (node->previous != NULL)
        {
            node->previous->next = node->next;
        }

        if (node->next != NULL)
        {
            node->next->previous = node->previous;
        }

        node->previous = NULL;
        node->next = NULL;
    }

    return node;
}

void dl_delete(DL_LIST *node, void (*destructor)(void*))
{
    assert(destructor != NULL);

    if (node != NULL)
    {
        dl_extract(node);

        if (node->object != NULL)
        {
            destructor(node->object);
        }

        free(node);
    }
}

DL_LIST *dl_get_first(DL_LIST *list)
{
    if (list != NULL)
    {
        while (list->previous != NULL)
        {
            list = list->previous;
        }
    }

    return list;
}

DL_LIST *dl_get_next(DL_LIST *node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        node = node->next;
    }

    return node;
}

void *dl_get_object(DL_LIST *node, uint16 *tag, uint32 *size)
{
    void *marker = NULL;

    if (node != NULL)
    {
        if (tag != NULL)
        {
            *tag = node->tag;
        }

        if (size != NULL)
        {
            *size = node->size;
        }

        marker = node->object;
    }

    return marker;
}

typedef struct QU_LIST
{
    DL_LIST *list;
    uint32 count;
} QU_LIST;

uint8 qu_remove(QU_LIST *queue, void *object, void (*destructor)(void*))
{
    uint8 result = QU_SUCCESS;
    uint32 size;
    DL_LIST *first_node;
    DL_LIST *next_node;
    void *marker;

    assert(queue != NULL && destructor != NULL);

    if (queue->count > 0)
    {
        first_node = dl_get_first(queue->list);
        next_node = dl_get_next(first_node);

        marker = dl_get_object(first_node, NULL, &size);

        if (marker != NULL)
        {
            if (object != NULL)
            {
                memcpy(object, marker, size);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = QU_NO_MEMORY;
        }

        queue->list = next_node;

        dl_delete(first_node, destructor); // this is the problem

        --queue->count;
    }
    else
    {
        result = QU_EMPTY;
    }

    return result;
}

DL_LIST *dl_get_last(DL_LIST *list)
{
    if (list != NULL)
    {
        while (list->next != NULL)
        {
            list = list->next;
        }
    }

    return list;
}

DL_LIST **qu_get_tail(QU_LIST *queue)
{
    DL_LIST *node = dl_get_last(queue->list);
    if(node)
        return &node->next;
    return &queue->list;
}

uint8 qu_add(QU_LIST *queue, uint16 tag, void *object, uint32 size)
{
  DL_LIST *node = malloc(sizeof *node), *prev;
  if(!node)
    return QU_NO_MEMORY;
  node->next = NULL;
  node->tag = tag;
  node->object = object;
  node->size = size;
  if(queue->list) {
      prev = dl_get_last(queue->list);
      prev->next = node;
      node->previous = prev;
  } else {
      queue->list = node;
      node->previous = NULL;
  }
  ++queue->count;
  return QU_SUCCESS;
}

void qu_init(QU_LIST *queue)
{
    queue->list = NULL;
    queue->count = 0;
}

void destroydata(void *data)
{
    memset(data, 'X', 3);
}

int main(void)
{
    char testdata[] = "ABC DEF GHI JKL!";
    char removed[4] = "";
    int i;
    QU_LIST q;

    qu_init(&q);
    if(qu_add(&q, 0, &testdata[0], 3) != QU_SUCCESS) abort();
    if(qu_add(&q, 1, &testdata[4], 3) != QU_SUCCESS) abort();
    if(qu_add(&q, 2, &testdata[8], 3) != QU_SUCCESS) abort();
    if(qu_add(&q, 3, &testdata[12], 3) != QU_SUCCESS) abort();
    puts("Done adding");
    for(i=0;i<4;++i) {
      if(qu_remove(&q, removed, destroydata) !=QU_SUCCESS) abort();
      printf("Removed: %s\n", removed);
      printf("testdata now contains: %s\n", testdata);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Superb answer - thank you for taking the time to have a play. I am currently yelling at my computer, trying to locate the source of the problem in the code that is not shown. If all else fails, I will append it to the end of my question. Thanks again.